# Minimizing display lag. Graphics software stack? Process priority? RTOS?

Tags: arch-linux, display, opengl, real-time

I am looking to come up with a setup to minimize display lag for psycophysics and electrophysiological reaction time experiments. I'm not talking about costly graphics computations on every frame, only showing a series of images on screen at the right time, and detecting user input. The lab currently uses Matlab to show images and is getting a time to screen of about 80ms (measured with photo-sensor close to the screen) on a windows machine. The most problematic thing is not the delay itself but the variability: if the delay is constant you can subtract it from the time you measure to get the real reaction time.

According to [this article](http://renderingpipeline.com/2013/09/measuring-input-latency/) they are various steps of image processing at different levels which might wait until the next frame, such that they add up, and you end up getting the wanted image on screen a few frames after you said so.

Anyway... I put Arch Linux on a machine that will be used only for this. It has an Intel graphics card and is connected to a VGA monitor. The idea is that there be little other software running when the experiment takes place. I would like advice on how to show the images. I don't need a desktop environment or a windows manager. I'm not sure if I even need X. I've read [this](http://blog.mecheye.net/2012/06/the-linux-graphics-stack/) and it seems that so much indirection might cost some latency. I know next to nothing about all of this, but I am willing to learn, so what I am looking for are general recommendations on where to direct my efforts.

There is also real time OSes (or kernel patches), like ChronOS or ART-Linux, but they seem to be useful on a finer time scale.

If all of this is too ambitious and seems like a lot of unnecessary work, I would still be happy if I can come up with anything at a lower level than matlab, which I'm guessing adds some overhead.

#### EDIT#1

I have found svgalib, which seems to be nice and simple (and old). I will try it out and see what happens.